# MySQL Double Join with Multiple Where Clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Why is this query not taking into account the Where clause of "c.max_no_people <= $max_guests"?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, b.post_id, c.max_no_people
FROM wp_dopbsp_reservations a
    INNER JOIN wp_dopbsp_calendars b
    ON ( b.id = a.calendar_id)
    INNER JOIN wp_dopbsp_settings c
    ON ( b.id = c.calendar_id )
WHERE (a.check_out >= \"$check_in\"
            AND a.check_in < \"$check_out\"
            OR a.check_out <= \"$check_in\"
            AND a.check_in > \"$check_out\")
    AND (c.max_no_people <= $max_guests)
    AND (a.status = 'approved')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, b.post_id, c.max_no_people
FROM wp_dopbsp_reservations a
INNER JOIN wp_dopbsp_calendars b
ON ( b.id = a.calendar_id)
INNER JOIN wp_dopbsp_settings c
ON ( b.id = c.calendar_id )
WHERE a.check_out >= \"$check_in\"
        AND (a.check_in < \"$check_out\"
        OR a.check_out <= \"$check_in\")
        AND a.check_in > \"$check_out\"
AND (c.max_no_people <= $max_guests)
AND (a.status = 'approved')
```

This was because you gave the OR statement without using the brackets in the condition where . So it will consider only the OR statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Weird, I still don't get the expected results. It's returning the reservations even if $max_guests is less than or equal to the one stored in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm i think the problem is here

```
(a.check_out >= \"$check_in\"
 AND a.check_in < \"$check_out\"
 OR a.check_out <= \"$check_in\"
 AND a.check_in > \"$check_out\")
```

Should it not be :

```
(
 (a.check_out >= \"$check_in\"
 AND a.check_in < \"$check_out\") OR
( a.check_out <= \"$check_in\"
 AND a.check_in > \"$check_out\")
)
```

Also escape the **$max_guests** like (int) $max_guests